# Poynting vector plane wave

Tags: electromagnetism, poynting-vector

I'm calculating the poynting vector for a plain wave and I have some doubt.

$$ \bar S = \frac 1 2  \bar E \times \bar  H^* = ... = \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} \hat i_k $$

Now if I consider a cylindrical volume and apply the divergence theorem I get

$$ \int_{s_1} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  = - \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} A$$
$$ \int_{s_2} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  = \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} A$$
$$ \int_{s_l} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  = 0$$

where $s_1$ is the left face, $s_2$ is the right face and $s_l$ is the lateral face of the cylinder.

So I should have 
$$ \int_{S} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  =  - \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta}A +\frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} A = 0$$

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is right: it is telling you "what goes in, comes out again"!

The plane wave does indeed bear energy. The two nonzero parts of your calculation:

$$ P_1=\int_{s_1} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  = - \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} A$$
$$ P_2=\int_{s_2} Re \,\, \bar S \,\,\hat i_n dS  = \frac {| \bar E|^2} {2 \zeta} A$$

are opposite in sign. What this is telling you is that whatever energy from the plane wave that goes into one end of the cylinder comes out again at the other.

It's analogous to a cylindrical hose with water going through it, with none being lost along the way (otherwise the hose would swell).

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the amount of energy the is radiated from a cylinder with no source, and only a plane wave going through it, and get 0... seems right to me... 
By the way, Re seems superfluous in you equations, since S is already real.